# Change attributes of animated elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I must admit I'm less than a genius in CSS... To practice, I'm creating an animation that simulates a beer glass.

For the moment and with my skills, I have a nice liquid animation and a great customized color picker **:)**.

Now I want to simulate liquid being drunk. **Click the liquid (colored) part to see the animation**

By changing `liquid` container, I've achieved simulate how the liquid goes away, 
http://jsfiddle.net/jm5c4qby/6/ But in the top part, the color is not the desired. As I'm moving the `wave` elements.

[image: issue with beer glass]

And I don't succeed when I try to increase the `height` of the `wave` elements:
http://jsfiddle.net/jm5c4qby/8/

```
$("#liquid").click(function(){
    bottom += 30;
    h += 30;
    $(".wave").animate({'bottom': bottom + "px", 'height': h + "%"}, 100);
});
```

I've tried with:

```
$(".wave").animate({'height': h + "%"}, 100);
```

or

```
$(".wave").animate({'bottom': bottom + "px"}, 100);
```

But I can't achieve the desired result...

Any ideas?

Comment: Nice work so far Jordi :)

Comment: I am getting seasick watching the demo... :) +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `click` function :

```
var padding = 0;

$("#liquid").click(function(){
    padding += 30;
    $(".wave").animate({'padding-bottom': padding + "px"}, 100);
});
```

This will increase your waves margin-bottom on each click. Also, **let `bottom` attribute always to zero !** It's seems weird that bottom is set to zero, but I found out that your `#liquid` is 180° rotated...yesterday when I first helped you! ;)

Comment: you're saving my life bro!! I knew I was close, but couldn't figure out why!! [working perfect now!](http://jsfiddle.net/jm5c4qby/10/)

Comment: So how about marking this as the correct answer? ;) Good luck for the continuation!

Comment: sure, only you're sp fast and there was a delay to accept an aswer after asking xDDDD, wait for some other question from me!!! jejeje.

Comment: Thanks! See you later in the questions feed for the next step haha

Comment: hehe... next thing will be change the glass shape, I need some nice cups, and great glasses for beer experts :D but I need to search and practice by myself first

Comment: As I come from Belgium, I may have some experience...!